# Cannot find module when Archiving in Xcode, but module is found during "Run"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I installed Heap Analytics manually by copy and pasting the files over (and then added it to bridging header).

When I run on a device, everything builds fine.  However, when I archive, the error is "No such module Heap".

Why is Archiving different than Running? Am I missing some configuration during the archiving process? As far as I know, nothing has been touched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I work for Heap and want to pass along that the poster ultimately found that deleting the data in the DerivedData folder cleared up the error:

```
rm -frd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not compile the line: `@import JavaScriptCore;` and the error given was `Module 'JavaScriptCore' not found`.
For me it was only necessary to delete the folder: `ModuleCache`.
The path was: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/`

In Terminal: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/*`